# UserNameWindows function in Excel not working for other users

Tags: excel

I've created a tool which is being used by multiple users who all have access to the shared folder the tool is saved in. In the tool I use the function UserNameWindows to pull in the username of the person using the tool. The function I use is =VLOOKUP(UserNameWindows(),T25:U34,2,FALSE) where the T25:U35 range is a mapping of user names to actual names.

The issue is that it works for me but my it's not pulling the username's of other users. Could it be that read-only is preventing the calculation from performing? I sat with one of the users to check and it's like the tool is remembering my Windows username from when I saved it.

Comment: Provide the code of your custom `UserNameWindows()` function as well

Answer (score 0):

You probably used Application.Username in the function and that is the username set in Microsoft Office. It will be blank if they have not set it in File>Options>General>User name.  Use Environ("Username") in your function and it will use the windows login username.